# freeglut error "Function called without first calling 'glutInit' " when using glut in a loop

Tags: python, freeglut

I would like to open and close a glut window several times in my program. I came up with this python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GL import *

#parameters for viewer
name = 'Viewer'
width, height = 500, 500
spheresize = 0.3

def display():
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluLookAt(0,0,10,0,0,0,0,1,0)
    glPushMatrix()           
    color = [1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0]
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT,GL_DIFFUSE,color)    
    glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,1.0)   
    glutSolidSphere(spheresize,20,20)  
    glPopMatrix()
    glutSwapBuffers()
    return                      

def closing():
   glutSetOption(GLUT_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE,GLUT_ACTION_GLUTMAINLOOP_RETURNS)         glutLeaveMainLoop()
   return                 

#---------------BEGIN PROGRAM----------------
while 1:
   glutInit()
   glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH)
   glutInitWindowSize(width,height)
   glutCreateWindow(name)
   glClearColor(0.,1.0,0.,1.)
   glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)
   glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)
   glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)  
   glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
   glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)

   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
   gluPerspective(40.,1.,1.,40.)
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
   glPushMatrix()

   glutDisplayFunc(display)
   glutCloseFunc(closing)

   glutMainLoop()

   print "\n\nMAIN MENUE:"
   print "p - print"
   print "q - quit"
   option = raw_input()

   if option == "q":
      raise SystemExit

   elif option == "p":
      print ("Hello World!")
```

When I try to run this, the window closes as I intended, but it crashes after using option 'p' with
**freeglut  ERROR:  Function glutCreateWindow called without first calling 'glutInit'.**

After I found some other posts about a similar problem, I assumed it might be a problem of my library linkage, so I tried to run it in a clean python environment on another computer. It gave the same error.

Does anyone have an idea what might be my mistake?

Comment: I can replicate this problem on Ubuntu 18 with pyopengl-3.1.5.  It's likely a bug in freeglut.

Comment: Similar problems on macOS 11.6 with freeglut 3.2.1, because src/osx is empty, and in particular lacks fg_init_osx.c whose fgPlatformInitialize() would have set fgState.Initialised to true, to avoid such errors.